# Dynamic Chart using Xamarin Forms

Tags: charts, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am newbie in Xamarin; I know there must be ready components for what I need, already I searched but not yet found.
I need to create a dynamic graphic like this:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update

I wore this in PhoneGap (html5 + JS), but now I'm moving to Xamarin forms and would like to know if any third component is what I need or I'll have to do everything from scratch.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently looking into graphing too and [OxyPlots](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/index.html) seems to be a pretty good line graph tool.  I don't think it supports dynamic updating so you'd have to program it to update manually when new data points come available.

I've not gotten round to actually using this myself but I thought I'd post this here in case it works for you.

Edit:  Here's a list of [examples](http://resources.oxyplot.org/examplebrowser/).  Also you can add it to your project using nuget so it should be easy to set up.

Comment: I've had a little play around with it and it does seem to work quite well.  FYI to install it from nuget you may need to check the 'search pre-release builds' check box.  That took me a while to figure out!

Comment: I Try OxyPlot ! It's amazing component ! Works Perfect !

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  I've only done basic things in it but it does seem really good :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [Syncfusion controls for Xamarin.Forms](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin) and I'm satisfied with it. They also have a free license for individual developers and small businesses.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically updated Xamarin charts SciChart offers an extremely high performance solution. With the SciChart Xamarin Chart control you can draw up to a million points, zoom, pan and scroll big datasets interactively.

[image: Scrolling Xamarin Chart]

Check out performance demos here:

- https://www.scichart.com/example/xamarin-chart-realtime-fifo-scrolling-chart-example/
- https://www.scichart.com/example/xamarin-chart-performance-demo-example/
- https://www.scichart.com/example/xamarin-chart-ecg-monitor-demo-example/

*Disclosure: I am the tech lead on the SciChart Xamarin project*